# Can someone identify some words for me in a short audio clip?

Tags: untagged

I read at level A2, but to improve listening ability, I listen to audio and follow along in the text.  Unfortunately, the people providing the audio are not reading the same text that I read.  Most of the differences are trivial, but one secton today was very different.

What was [online](https://www2.bible.com/nl/bible/1197/DAN.7.icl00) said, "Poi ne verrà un altro, diverso dai precedenti; abbatterà tre re," but what it sounds like to me is "Un ____ re, diverso da gli altri; ___ potere __ da parte altri tre re."

I've copied [that part of the audio](https://HappyHobo.net/Daniele_7.mp3) onto my website.  I wonder whether someone would be kind enough to listen to https://HappyHobo.net/Daniele_7.mp3 and fill in the blanks for me (and fix the rest if I've misheard it)?

I couldn't find a suitable pre-existing tag—is this off-topic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure whether the question is on topic or not, let's see what the other users decide. For now I will only answer that the required sentence is:

> Un undicesimo re, diverso dagli altri, prenderà il potere dopo aver messo da parte altri tre re

It seems to be part of the [Traduzione interconfessionale in lingua corrente](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parola_del_Signore_-_La_Bibbia_in_lingua_corrente), which can be found  [here](http://www.lachiesa.it/bibbia.php?ricerca=citazione&Versione_TILC=2&VersettoOn=1,27&Citazione=Dn%207,15-27).

Comment: Yes, that is the source; but apparently an older or newer edition.  I see that bibbia.net says "version sperimentale."  Now I have another place to look if I run into another mismatch.